# Error with Map in Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, map, before-trigger, loop

I have 2 custom objects (`Workload_Unit_Score__c`, `Agreement_Title__c`).  The `WLU_combination_Value__C` and `Score__c` fields are on both objects.

I want a trigger on the `Agreement_Title__c` object that, once a new record is created, looks for a matching `WLU_Combination_Value__c` on the `Workload_Unit_Score__c` object, and returns a `Score__c` to be populated on the same field on the `Agreement_Title__c` object.

Whenever I run the code I get the following error:

> "Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a
>   concrete SObject: Map at line 16 column
>   39"

Can someone help me?

```
trigger updateWLUvalue2 on Agreement_Title__c (before insert){

   Map<String,Workload_Unit_Score__c> wus= new Map<String,Workload_Unit_Score__c>();

   for (Agreement_Title__c agmtt : Trigger.new){
      wus.put(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c,null);
   }

   wusByWLU = New Map<String,Workload_Unit_Score__c>();

   for(Workload_Unit_Score__c wus : [
      Select WLU_Combination_Value__c,Score__c 
      FROM Workload_Unit_Score__c
      WHERE WLU_Combination_Value__c
      IN : wus.keySet()
    ]){
      wusByWLU.put(wus.WLU_Combination_Value__c,wus);  
    }

 for(Agreement_Title__c agmtt: Trigger.new){

  if(wusByWLU.containsKey(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c)){
    Workload_Unit_Score__c wluScore = wusByWLU.get(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c);
    agmtt.Workload_Unit_Score__c = wluScore.Score__c;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do these

```
wus = New Map<String,Workload_Unit_Score__c>([
  Select WLU_Combination_Value__c,Score__c 
  FROM Workload_Unit_Score__c
  WHERE WLU_Combination_Value__c
  IN : wus.keySet()
]);
```

The key of the map is the id of the record, not the WLU_Combination_Value__c.

You need change these part to:

```
wusByWLU = New Map<String,Workload_Unit_Score__c>();

for(Workload_Unit_Score__c wus : [
  Select WLU_Combination_Value__c,Score__c 
  FROM Workload_Unit_Score__c
  WHERE WLU_Combination_Value__c
  IN : wus.keySet()
]){
  wusByWLU.put(wus.WLU_Combination_Value__c,wus);  
}
```

And when you are relating the workload_uit_Score__c with the agreement you need verify that you have a workload_uit_Score__c for that WLU.

```
for(Agreement_Title__c agmtt: Trigger.new){

  if(wusByWLU.containsKey(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c)){
    Workload_Unit_Score__c wluScore = wusByWLU.get(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c);
    agmtt.Workload_Unit_Score__c = wluScore.Score__c;
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2 TRIGGER COMPLETE:**

```
    trigger updateWLUvalue2 on Agreement_Title__c (before insert){

  Set<String> wluValues = new Set<String>();
  Map<String,Workload_Unit_Score__c> wLU= new Map<String,Workload_Unit_Score__c>();
  for (Agreement_Title__c agmtt : Trigger.new){
    wluValues.add(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c);
  }

  Map<String,Workload_Unit_Score__c> wusByWLU = New Map<String,Workload_Unit_Score__c>();

  for(Workload_Unit_Score__c wus : [
    Select WLU_Combination_Value__c,Score__c 
    FROM Workload_Unit_Score__c
    WHERE WLU_Combination_Value__c
    IN :wluValues
  ]){
    wusByWLU.put(wus.WLU_Combination_Value__c,wus);  
  }

 for(Agreement_Title__c agmtt: Trigger.new){

    if(wusByWLU.containsKey(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c)){
      Workload_Unit_Score__c wluScore = wusByWLU.get(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c);
      agmtt.Workload_Unit_Score__c = wluScore.Score__c;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! I made these updates but am getting one (probably minor) error: "Compile error: Duplicate variable: wus at line 11 column 31"  Apologies, Apex (triggers especially) are very new to me still...

Comment: Here is your code read edit 2

Comment: -@Torsen @Ratan I was able to get the code to work with both of your help - thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

issue in last line ie. `agmtt.Workload_Unit_Score__c = wus.Score__c;`

this should be

```
agmtt.Workload_Unit_Score__c = wluScore.Score__c;
```

or

```
agmtt.Workload_Unit_Score__c = wus.get(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c).Score__c;
```

### Updates

Add `conatainsKey` check Id is contains in map or not.

```
//your rest code

for(Agreement_Title__c agmtt: Trigger.new)
{
    //Add this check so we will get only those records which are present in map 
    if(wus.containsKey(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c))
    {
        Workload_Unit_Score__c wluScore = wus.get(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c);
        agmtt.Workload_Unit_Score__c = wluScore.Score__c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I tried both and they allowed me to save the trigger, which is progress.  Now I am getting the following error message with both, when I tried testing it out by creating a new record on the Agreement_Title__c object:                                  Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger updateWLUvalue caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: updateWLUvalue: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.updateWLUvalue: line 16, column 1

Comment: @Clink can you update your question with your latest code and let me review your code..

Comment: Sure, I have updated it now.  Only difference is the bottom line.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Clink you are welcome.. Please check my updates above.

Comment: Thanks again for you help. I updated the code above and am getting one final error: "Compile error: Duplicate variable: wus at line 11 column 31"  Im hoping this is a minor error.  Apologies, Apex (triggers especially) are very new to me still...